# C# : Generate Unique Local IPv6 Address Prefix

Tags: c#, ipv6

I am trying to generate the unique Local IPv6 address prefix ( Given in link https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4193) **Section:3.2.2.  Sample Code for Pseudo-Random Global ID Algorithm**

Steps are given below here as well...

1. Obtain the current time of day in 64-bit NTP format [NTP].

   2. Obtain an EUI-64 identifier from the system running this
      algorithm.  If an EUI-64 does not exist, one can be created from
      a 48-bit MAC address as specified in [ADDARCH].  If an EUI-64
      cannot be obtained or created, a suitably unique identifier,
      local to the node, should be used (e.g., system serial number).
   3. Concatenate the time of day with the system-specific identifier
      in order to create a key.
   4. Compute an SHA-1 digest on the key as specified in [FIPS, SHA1];
      the resulting value is 160 bits.
   5. Use the least significant 40 bits as the Global ID.
   6. Concatenate FC00::/7, the L bit set to 1, and the 40-bit Global
      ID to create a Local IPv6 address prefix.

This algorithm will result in a Global ID that is reasonably unique
and can be used to create a locally assigned Local IPv6 address
prefix.

**I just wanted to know is there any C# built-in method or any nuget package available that does it, or would be helpful if anyone can provide the c# code for it.**

I guess in C#, it is called as IPv6SiteLocal.

Comment: Did you try something already?

Comment: The first 48 bits are assigned by your IP carrier and you cannot change these values.  The subnet and ID can be assigned inside the range of addresses given to you by your carrier.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski...not yet...before trying I wanted to know if there is any already exiting  way to get it.

Comment: "_I guess in C#, it is called as IPv6SiteLocal._" No, IPv6 Site Local Addressing was deprecated in favor of IPv6 Unique Local Addressing.